# Group product price is featuring as $0.00 in the wishlist section in the Customer Account Magento2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, wishlist

If I add any group product to the wishlist, then the product price display $0.00 In the customer account the Wishlist section.

How to add the **minimal-price** in the wishlsit in the customer account.

[image]

Comment: Does anybody have any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved it myself, I hope it would be helpful to other developers.

extend the wishlist_index_index.xml file in your theme and add the below code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.price.render.wishlist">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
            <argument name="price_label" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>                  
</body>
```

below is the output  screenshot.

[image]